# Redeclare class generic

Tags: typescript

I've created a class in TypeScript which uses a generic to allow for method type checking. To simplify:

```
class Schema<PropType extends Record<string, any>> {
  props: Partial<PropType> = {};
  
  constructor(props: PropType) {
    this.props = props;
  }

  pick(...propNames: Array<keyof PropType>) {
    return new Schema(propNames.reduce(
      (obj, key) => ({ ...obj, [key]: this.props[key] }),
      {}
    ));
  }

  set(key: string, value: any) {
    return new Schema({ ...this.props, [key]: value });
  }
}
```

The purpose of this is to provide type-safety when calling `pick`, or one of the other methods (not shown here), where prop keys are needed:

```
const Person = new Schema({ firstName: 'Fyodor', lastName: 'Dostoevsky' });
Person.pick('firstName'); // No issues
Person.pick('madeup'); // Issues
```

The problem is, when I change the object and declare a new class, it doesn't seem to extend a new `PropType` type:

```
const Person = new Schema({ firstName: 'Fyodor', lastName: 'Dostoevsky' });
Person.pick('firstName'); // Works
Person.pick('middleName'); // Shows appropriate type error

const JustFirst = Person.pick('firstName')
JustFirst.pick('firstName'); // Not allowed?!? Error: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

const ExtraPerson = Person.set('middleName', 'Mikhailovich');
ExtraPerson.pick('middleName', 'butNothingIsTyped'); // Typing is expanded to any `Record<string, any>`, so no errors
```

See this [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKwAsCmBbMAeACgJwPYAcAVAT3yWiQA8AXJAOwBMYAlJYXbB9Ca7ASzoBzADTQwdYgD5J0AN4AoaNHx58EAFzRMYbNT5gQWVSTIyAvHIC%20AbkXQ77Oj2wBXYNQ4AKFQQ1bjpEgAlHJ2StQIfBAAdD5q0BZxELZKlvJ2%20HzAANae0flxAHJgKEh%20AILY2GDE6NlIxLgAZv4EJkiSIQpKSthI1C7YdNB0SADucIioYN6qxaUxfQxuSJ5hPZ64AEYAVqL1xCFmMp6y0PnR23vQANoHALqaEVGxqhB3DffQlkHC60qyNI9aBBIIpb7pJQQfqeA6aZwCETQABuBhcSE04kOoWBfQGQxG40myDQp3O%20WeMSSog%20xEeKLR5B%204LSaXkjh4WiQ2AguGGFlGE3gJJmZyafB51HmGOgAHIAGKNBgcWWicA8aWaWUAEVwPFwSGREGyxFl3zB8kw3N5dFiWVysvFkulsot7L5nIAUi4ePKJZyLFaeXy7TlPI7-VKSkhXfJvb7I6GHU6NdHXdZoAB6TPQQq4ahiEAgXBjJAMAD86Q5BYAojRqkGbQkucHbdDqOGUHwGAwQEgXaJZQBZPjZBBgPjF5FZBDp%20R13hgRshzJh2Vdnt9gdyrYuKX5yJCACSEHaDHTWZzJkR0Ci0FwyO5rj7DHS8iAA). Is there a way to have the generic `PropType` essentially re-initialized/extended with each initialization of the parent class?

**EDIT:**

I've figured out a solution to `set` in particular, which I think works:

```
  set<K extends string, V extends unknown>(key: K, value: V) {
    return new Schema<PropType & Record<K, V>>({ ...this.props as PropType, [key]: value });
  }
```

Comment: You're running into two separate problems. The first is that `pick()` uses the initial value of `{}` from the reduce as its `PropType`. Hence no matter what you try to pick, it won't be valid. To fix this, one option would be to type the initial value and/or the return type of `pick()`. The second problem is that `set()` uses the default value of `PropType`, which is `Record<string, any>` so any key will become valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with some help from @Etheryte! Example below, but [here's the link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKwAsCmBbMAeACgJwPYAcAVAT3yWiQA8AXJAOwBMYAlJYXbB9Ca7ASzoBzADTQArnQDWdXAHc6APgXQA3gCho0fHnwQAXNExhs1PmBBYdJMsoC8qgL4BuDdHZ0e2McGocAFNoE%20oZWpEgAlKqumtQIfBAAdIG60PbJMJAhBNZILpoOaq74fMCS6ADSFDT0TNCSSMS4AGZZRGEKfgldyQByYChIwQCC2NhgxBUKkeqamthI1GLYdNB0SLJwiKgYrOycFaIS0nKKHb39gwnzDN5IftGzfrgARgBWBmB0xKL1xAblkVsyj8KmgXQSL1eogA2r8ALoGWLxJI6CCwhpw6AOcLCB6aFQFWbQcLhPJYwqaXAoPjUCpVWiMGC-ZqtHIdcHnAbDUbjSbTB7uHjQXwAeWp1AMRhMZgsOGy7VSWh0fS5VyQN2Adyebx%20gOBoPBkJhkgRwq85GxogJpIe1DC0B663KDUVzJaYpplnlZFE5QUD3mi2Wq3Wm2QaHQuw4XEdsmd33EUhk8iUfhFbzY1ASvwgfiRiXS4TVGrueOg2ve0E%20Cd%20BjdrLCeuFuA91HRxExAH5oJDoAYQWCukboO3TfmUUFR1icWWCQ8SWSCq4IAs6VQGbVPAIRNAAGr0mowI7JxR%20WvQcqiABu5jESAMu-5RMDSxWaw28HDGDlbTI0AAZNAUb7Jee6pgaXTjukVYwD%20OTGhiBg3iAd7TouahLoK1CGEg2AQLgKz2O%20YbbAOTR8Hh1Aqve0AAOQAGKNAwHC0aI4A8NRBi0QAIrgPC4EgV4QJIxC0WhaiYLh%20F0EkJSSH4tHkZR1G0TaahYdAABSYg8PRFFCvYkl4QRsmlApSkcRcqlqNpun6VmxRmYp9kqaS0AAPTudAQwgCAcjqjZOnUHplGmfJznKVZoi0exVFWW5nkOrg2HmH5sgBepBFCrZwX2QATIqRnSRC4oKbFrkuDlIU8HlYV%20AARBZcUDPVkSJQA6hwkgQIFdmUbVjnyfV5UXK1TgeV5vGDHQtEAISFBpPkgIVUkmYNDVNdR9WiMNkDNUgY2ZR42EAKI0GMRUEYqS0JCu1AKdSDAMCASAqdFACyfCSAgYB8H5V4lAgqkuGdvBgJdMnrbRj3Pa9UV0TI1BDMAmr4NQYDPC9rHQLtlktQlXkinQIDEMKYQMHUDQZPMVa%20f5DCFGoQA).

```
class Schema<PropType extends Record<string, unknown>> {
  props: Partial<PropType> = {};
  constructor(props: PropType) {
    this.props = props as PropType;
  }

  pick<K extends keyof PropType>(...propNames: Array<K>) {
    return new Schema<Record<K, unknown>>(propNames.reduce(
      (obj: any, key: K) => ({ ...obj, [key]: this.props[key] }),
      {}
    ));
  }

  omit<K extends keyof PropType>(...propNames: Array<K>) {
    const toOmit: Partial<PropType> = propNames.reduce((obj, k) => ({ ...obj, [k]: true }), {});
    type NewKey = keyof Omit<PropType, K>
    return new Schema<Record<NewKey, unknown>>(Object.keys(this.props).reduce(
      (obj: any, key: keyof PropType) => toOmit[key] ? obj : ({ ...obj, [key]: this.props[key] }),
      {}
    ));
  }

  set<K extends string, V extends unknown>(key: K, value: V) {
    return new Schema<PropType & Record<K, V>>({ ...this.props as PropType, [key]: value });
  }
}

const Person = new Schema({ firstName: 'Fyodor', lastName: 'Dostoevsky' });
Person.pick('firstName');

const JustFirst = Person.pick('firstName')
JustFirst.pick('firstName'); // Allowed
JustFirst.pick('firstName', 'lastName'); // Not allowed

const JustFirst2 = Person.omit('lastName');
JustFirst2.pick("firstName") // Works
JustFirst2.pick("lastName"); // Doesn'!

const All = Person.pick("firstName", "lastName");
const ExtraPerson = All.set('middleName', 'Mikhailovich');
ExtraPerson.pick('middleName', 'notAcceptable', "lastName"); // Only typed keys are allowed, so middleName and lastName are good, but notAcceptable is not
```

Comment: Nice, good job!